# Argparse subparser: hide metavar in command listing

Tags: python, argparse

I'm using the Python argparse module for command line subcommands in my program. My code basically looks like this:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(title="subcommands", metavar="<command>")

subparser = subparsers.add_parser("this", help="do this")
subparser = subparsers.add_parser("that", help="do that")

parser.parse_args()
```

When running "python test.py --help" I would like to list the available subcommands. Currently I get this output:

```
usage: test.py [-h] <command> ...

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit

subcommands:
  <command>
    this      do this
    that      do that
```

Can I somehow remove the `<command>` line in the subcommands listing and still keep it in the usage line? I have tried to give help=argparse.SUPPRESS as argument to add_subparsers, but that just hides all the subcommands in the help output.

Comment: What about setting `metavar` to `None` (or leaving it off)? -- Or setting `metavar=''` ...

Comment: Thanks for answering! If I set it to None I just get a list of all the commands instead and if I use `metavar=''` I get an empty line. In both cases I lose the metavar in the usage line.

Comment: Oh, I get what you're looking for now.  Unfortunately I don't know how to make it happen.

Comment: I think I need to implement a custom HelpFormatter

Comment: That would do it, unfortunately, `Argparse` doesn't really expose enough of it's internals to make it easy to create custom `HelpFormatter` objects.

Answer (score 20):

I solved it by adding a new HelpFormatter that just removes the line if formatting a PARSER action:

```
class SubcommandHelpFormatter(argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter):
    def _format_action(self, action):
        parts = super(argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter, self)._format_action(action)
        if action.nargs == argparse.PARSER:
            parts = "\n".join(parts.split("\n")[1:])
        return parts
```

Comment: Awesome solution. +1 for solving an irritating problem in a simple way.

Comment: Thanks for the method. Works as expected when added to: `argparse.ArgumentParser(formatter_class=SubcommandHelpFormatter)`